# Clarifying then negating a sentence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

> There is a prime number $p$ such that $P(p, q)$ is true for all prime numbers $q = p$.

Notice that the given statement goes "there is a prime number $p$" followed by "$P(p, q)$ is true" and then followed by "for all prime numbers $q = p$". However, when writing it in math symbols, I put "$\forall q$" before "$P(p, q)$ is true", correct?

Given the information above, is this negation correct?

- Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of prime numbers.

  $$\neg(\exists p {\in}\mathbb{P} \; \space \forall q {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \space q = p \space \text{ such that } P(p, q))$$

  $$\forall p {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \space \exists q {\in} \mathbb{P}\; \space q = p \space \text{ such that } \neg P(p, q)$$

  For all prime numbers $p$, there is a prime number $q$ equal to p, for which $P(p, q)$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

Your rectification of the [hanging quantifier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207357/21813) and final answer are both good, however your translations and intermediate step are incorrect.

> > There is a prime number $p$ such that $P(p, q)$ is true for all prime numbers $q = p$.
>
> $$\neg(\exists p {\in}\mathbb{P} \; \space \forall q {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \space q = p \space \textbf{ such that } P(p, q))$$

In this intermediate step, what you've written means $$\neg\Big(\exists p {\in}\mathbb{P} \; \forall q {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \big(q = p \; \land \; P(p, q) \big)\Big),$$ whereas the correct negation is $$\neg\Big(\exists p {\in}\mathbb{P} \; \forall q {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \big(q = p  \,\to\, P(p, q) \big)\Big);$$ translating this clunkily to make clear how your placement of "such that" is wrong:

- "it is not that there exists a prime $p$ **such that** for each prime $q$ **such that** $q=p,$ $P(p,q)$."

> $$\forall p {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \space \exists q {\in} \mathbb{P}\;
>  \space q = p \space \textbf{ such that } \neg P(p, q)$$

This final step, though, is technically correct; however, this if you want to spell out the "such that"s, then it is more consistent to write    $$\forall p {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \space \exists q {\in} \mathbb{P}\;
 \textbf{ such that } \space q = p \space \textbf{ such that } \space \neg P(p, q);$$ however, $$\forall p {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \space \exists q {\in} \mathbb{P}\;
 \textbf{ such that } \space q = p \space \textbf{ and } \space \neg P(p, q),$$ is more natural, and $$\forall p {\in} \mathbb{P}\;  \space \exists q {\in} \mathbb{P}\;
 \big(q = p \;\land\; \neg P(p, q)\big)$$ is best.